# Multiple Packages using One AS File, Variable Initialization Issue 'Coercion Failed'

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, mxml

I have two packages

```
import ph.package1.*;
import ph.package2.*;
```

Main Reason why I used different packages is to separate the views on my FB4.6 Mobile Application because I want to create specific views to cater different mobile and tablet resolutions.

So basically, the two have the same files, filenames, but they only vary on the layout and styles. I only used one AS files from one package to prevent redundancy, and so far it is working okay. App is working on most pages.

Now the problem is this, on one of my action scripts, I have this code:

```
var counter:Counter = this["counter"];
```

*Assumptions*

- Current View is from Package1
- AS File is called from Package2
- Both Packages contain Counter.mxml

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert ph.package1.Counter to ph.package2.Counter....

How can I resolve this so that the variable initialization will point to the other package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the whole namespace:

```
var counter:ph.package1.Counter = this["counter"];
```

But anyway while packages are meant to avoid those conflicts it is still a good idea to give different class names. Imagine if you had 20 classes with exactly the same name that would be a nightmare.

Comment: Nice, didn't know I can do that one. Well as for the same name issue on different packages, was thinking of creating a function that will set the packages... no idea how to do that though.

Comment: btw, when I used the whole namespace on instantiating the variable I still got the same error `Error #1034: Type Coercion failed`.

Comment: Then use the other package namespace, it's one or the other anyway.

Comment: thanks for the help @botmaster one last question, would it be possible to use a variable on variable type insted of the whole path?

Comment: if you mix within the same code 2 or more object with the same class names then you need to use the whole path every time in your code to avoid conflicts. This is the down side of giving same class names to objects you know you'll have to work with in same scope. Like I said before even though you can do it it's better to just give different names, you'll avoid those annoying little problems and you'll be able to recognize which is which.